# Haskell - How to bypass lazy evaluation in updating arguments in a tail-recursive function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, tail-recursion

Here is a Haskell function that takes a number `n` and returns the nth fibonacci number. (I've used the index scheme such that the 0th number is 0, the 1st number is 1, 2nd number is 1, 3rd number is 2, and so on.)

```
fib :: (Integral a) => a -> a
fib 0 = 0
fib n = fibhelper n 0 1

fibhelper :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a -> a
fibhelper 1 x y = y
fibhelper n x y = fibhelper (n-1) y (x+y)
```

Now, suppose that, for the sake of efficiency, I want to bypass Haskell's lazy evaluation and force the evaluation of the updated arguments (using the `$!` operator, for instance?) What would be the most elegant/idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You're probably looking for [bang patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bang patterns to do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

fib :: (Integral a) => a -> a
fib 0 = 0
fib n = fibhelper n 0 1

-- Everything with a ! before it will be evaluated before the function body
fibhelper :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a -> a
fibhelper 1 _ (!y) = y
fibhelper (!n) (!x) (!y) = fibhelper (n-1) y (x+y)
-- The above line is equivalent to:
--fibhelper n x y = n `seq` x `seq` y `seq` fibhelper (n-1) y (x+y)
```

Note also that you're a bit overzealous with the use of the `Integral` type class. Do you really want the index of the fibonacci series to be the same type as the values? I would suggest that you instead use the signature:

```
fib :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Also, if you are looking for performance, the use of `Integral` should be avoided entirely.

Comment: You don't even need `Integral` for the result, `Num` will do fine. I'm worried about your bang patterns, though - isn't it the case that `fibhelper 1 undefined 0` is `0`, and hence the function isn't strict?

Comment: Well, yeah, I didn't put a bang pattern before the `_`, and the patterns still match top-down. So, if the runtime sees that the first argument is `1`, the first definition of `fibhelper` will apply, where the `_` argument isn't forced.

Comment: it would seem you don't need to force `x` anyway since it receives the previously forced `y`.